# How to calculate time period of process

Tags: python, image

Good day! I have interesting question. I need to count time period of process, what i have in my code. It's one frame, on what i am using face - detection.

Output file is same frame, but with paint rectangles on it. So, the problem is count time from the input of frame before output already finished one. 
I will be happy in someone can help to me with it! 
Have a good day~

Comment: Hello. It would be useful if you would also post some code that you worked or tried on. I'm not sure if you want to count the time of a running process as OS process, or a running function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from time import time

# before function is called 
t1 = time()
some_ouptut = do_some_processing(image_input)
print("Time to run {}.".format(time()-t1)
```

I presume you want to time the processing time for the function/painting square. `time()` will get the current time and you can take away the current time after running the process to get elapsed time.